# Compare Types of LLVM values

Tags: c++, c, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to **compare a llvm Type and a Type***. I'm using the LLVM C APIs. Is there any possible method to do this?

I have **Type*** because I did LLVMTypeOf api to get the type from an LLVM Value. So if I can get the **Type from a Value**, it would also fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Types are unique in LLVM world, so you could compare their addresses.

Answer (score 2):

To make it clear, and extend prior answers with a proper `llvm-c` code example, you just compare two `LLVMTypeRef` like you would compare any two pointers to check if they are equal.

```c
LLVMTypeRef type1 = whatever1();  // e.g. LLVMTypeOf(...)
LLVMTypeRef type2 = whatever2();  // e.g. LLVMDoubleType()
if (type1 == type2)
{
    // the two types are equal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly compare LLVM types of two values. e.g. see:

llvm/lib/Analysis/BasicAliasAnalysis.cpp:967

```
          GEP1->getPointerOperandType() == GEP2->getPointerOperandType() &&
```

Comment: Im using c api. Hence have no access to what u mentioned i guess

Comment: Can you use LLVMGetTypeKind? Each type returns a unique LLVMTypeKind.

Comment: Yeah but will it throw two different types for Type and Type*?

Comment: It only takes a LLVMTypeRef, so only one will work I think.

Comment: Are you trying to compare Types of two different Values?

Comment: Hey, no the issue is I have to compare a pointer to a type and a type.

Comment: You should be able to get Type from Type*, no? and then compare the two types.

Comment: Thats the question. I cant figure it out how to get the type from type* from llvm c apis. Thanks for all the clarifications you have done so far as well

Comment: Can you use: `LLVMTypeRef LLVMTypeOf(LLVMValueRef Val)` by passing an object of type `Type`. Another approach would be to use `LLVMTypeRef LLVMGetTypeByName(LLVMModuleRef M, const char *Name);` by passing the name of `Type*`.